# Complicated Regex Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text inputs with the following format:

[**PARENT**]-[OPTION]-[OPTION]

*For example*

1. **BIKE**-XT-MM-LX-100-BB
2. **TRICYCLE**-MM-XP
3. **MOTORBIKE**-X100V  *(-X100V isn't an option here)*

I am using *regular expressions* to separate **options** from the **parent**.
Separating the option aren't as easy as you can see, due to some exceptions.
anything followed by dash should be an option other than anything starting with X and longer than two digits, such as example #3 which -X100V isn't an option. 
Then I went with expressions such as these to separate the chunks:

```
// Only separates 2 digit options, but we have more digit options:
(\A[^-]+)(-\w\w\b)+  

// 2 digits and more option which -X100V fits into also. but not an option:     
(\A[^-]+)(-\w{2,}\b)+

// which separates any 2 digit and longer followed by dash as an option 
// unless it is started with X (which rules out my 2 digit -XX options by mistake):
(\A[^-]+)(-[^\BX]\w{1,}\b)+
```

Now I need only one more step, to add a rule to only eliminated the case with are starting with -X but are longer than two digits, then I can include examples like -XT again.

I would love to hear the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for a regular expression here. Just use `String.Split` and split on the hyphen. You can then re-combine the first one if you need if it isn't an "option" and should be part of the "PARENT".

Something like:

```
var inputString = /*your input string, e.g. "BIKE-XT-MM-LX-100-BB"*/;
var parts = inputString.Split('-');

var parent = parts.First();
var options = parts.Skip(1).ToList();

//put back any non-"option"s
while(options.Any() && options.First().StartsWith("X") && 
    options.First().Length > 3)
{
    parent = String.Format("{0}-{1}", parent, options.First());
    options.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: @Ic. really appreciate your answer. I actually ended up doing the same. however, regular expressions are powerful tools to land the same result in a very short and fairly readable line of code and I mainly want to learn how to do that type of twist thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show a full text input it would be helpful.

Based on what you've shown us so far, the regex to separate the parent from the options would be simply:

`\A\w+(?=-)`

1. Assert position at the beginning of the string `\A`. You can also use `^`
2. Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) `\w+`
3. Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
4. Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) `(?=-)`
5. Match the character “-” literally `-`

Answer (score 0):

perform a regex split using this pattern `-(?!X[^-\r\n]{2})` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yK9mC4)